# Poisson distribution simple question

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I am missing something very simple here.

I am given that the number of printing errors on any random page of a book of $N$ pages follows a poisson variate with parameter $\lambda$. The number of pages in a random sample of $n$ pages (where $N>>n$ and $n\geq2$) which contain fewer than $2$ errors is denoted by $Y$. Then one has to show that $P(Y=k) = {n \choose k} p^{k}q^{n-k}$ where $p=(1+\lambda)e^{-\lambda}$.

I am quite oblivious to this result...

Comment: Well, $p$ is the probability that a given page has $____$ errors hence the binomial distribution with parameters $(n,p)$ indeed describes the number of errors in $n$ pages provided one assumes that $__________$. (On the other hand, the hypothesis that $n\ll N$ is offtopic and unnecessary.)

Answer (score 1):

the probability of zero or one error on any page is $$e^{-\lambda}+\lambda e^{-\lambda}=p$$
Then the number of pages in this condition follows a Binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$